# tmux Escape key exits server

Tags: bash, shell, tmux

I'm using tmux on a macOsX moutain lion (10.8)

Whenever i'm in a terminal, pressing the Escape button results in the connection to the server being lost and tmux actually exiting. I experience the same behavior regardless in iterm2, terminal and while using any of zsh, bash or a normal login shell.

That's how it looks like:

[image]

Any hints? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out that it was related to iterm2-tmux integration.

As you can read [here](http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/wiki/TmuxIntegration) in the Usage section just below the code box, the tmux-iterm2 integration makes the `ESC` key actually kill tmux, unless you actually use `tmux -C`.

This effect was actually undersirable for me since I was not using `tmux -C` and the `ESC` key is extremely important in programs like `vim` or `mc`.